# Where to put the script?

Tags: unity, c#, rpg

I watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uhnh8zj_VPo
and my question is where to put the script? I'm a complete noob here but I've at least build a map and moving player character. Yes, Unity please. TQ!

Comment: The video is titled "Make An RPG Episode 8: Turn-Base Combat Part 1". Wasn't this explained in the previous 7 episodes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research-effort. Any basic tutorial covers this.

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, scripts are usually attached as script components to game objects to control their behavior.

- Click on the game object in the scene hierarchy tree
- Click on "Add Component" in the inspector
- Select "Script" to add an existing script or "New Script" to create a new one.

Alternatively you can also drag the script file from the project folders directly onto the game object.

By the way, this happens in 5:43 of the video you posted. The author attaches the script to the "Main Camera" of their scene. But I would not recommend this. The only scripts attached to the camera should be those which control the camera. Attaching the script to the player game object might also work, but would also be weird. The "Player" object should only contain scripts which control the player character.

When you have any scripts which control the behavior of the scene as a whole, I would rather recommend to use a new, dedicated game object as a carrier for such scripts. A common convention is to call this game object "Game System".